# Setting http request in session

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have a requirement in which user do advance search based on the search criteria defined ( some complex business logic ). Now from search result user can navigate to different pages. There is a button  on one page and if user click on that button, page should navigate to search result page.

To navigate to search result i have two options :

1. Put all the search result in the session but this is not good. Search can have 1500+ rows.
2. Put search String in the session so that i can pull out that string and do query again.

Search String is dynamically created and there are number of query combinations there. I can't do this.

I am thinking that my problem will solve if i put http request in session. How's the idea? I never come across and have seen to put http request in the session. Is it good as per the standard?

Need your input.

Comment: do you fetch/display the 1500+ results or just a "page" ?

Comment: as of now 500 result on the page. page is having data table with pagination

Comment: Putting HttpRequest object in the Session is a bad idea, because that will prevent the request object from being garbage-collected when the request is finished.  Search string in session is far more typical.

Comment: Spring and Java EE together?

Comment: Might it be workable to store the parameter Map (request.getParameterMap()) in the session instead?